# Error - Unsuccessful: drop table if exists user - Springboot and H2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am getting the following errors in Intellij whilst trying to connect to a H2 database.

`Hibernate: create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))`

`2022-11-22 15:53:11.743  WARN 13376 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement`

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement`

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "create table [*]user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:`

`create table user (id bigint not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id)) [42001-214]`

`could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into user (email, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

My Code:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Stream.of("John", "Julie", "Jennifer", "Helen", "Rachel").forEach(name -> {
                User user = new User(name, name.toLowerCase() + "@domain.com");
                userRepository.save(user);
            });
            userRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    } //* for reference
}
```

The code from "@Bean" to the "//*" seems to be causing the error, as when deleted it has no errors when running. However unsure how to word it in order to not receive the error. [Following this tutorial.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20and%20Angular%20form,creating%20a%20JavaScript-based%20frontend.)

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class UserController {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return (List<User>) userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    void addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String email;

    public User() {
        this.name = "";
        this.email = "";
    }

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + '}';
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

**What I have tried **

I have read gone through some previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626089/hibernate-schema-is-automatically-dropped-on-deploy) and adjusted the application.properties to include the dialect as most places have mention this as the issue.

As stated I have removed the marked code in Application.java and the it seems to be fine once that has been done so that area I feel is the issue.

Comment: Have you userRepository class and market it as @Repository in the example tutorial that you shared ?

Comment: Yep got the userRepository

Comment: Can you share user repository class code as well ?

Comment: import com.example.demo.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I found that if I removed this from the application properties

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

And Added:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions = true
```

Comment: the `hibernate.globally*` properties worked for me.  I don't define the dialect to use, instead relying on Spring detecting it based on the driver in use.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there are some reserved keywords in `H2`, and one of them is `User`. You are creating a user table with the word `User`, which is reserved in `H2`. Try changing the table name to something other than User, such as Users. Alternatively, when you are writing the database URL in `application.properties`, add `;NON_KEYWORD=USER`. You can find other reserved words of H2 [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords).

Answer (score 0):

Use `int` instead of `long` with:

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

(not `GenerationType.AUTO`) and also make repository class as extends `CrudRepository<User, Integer>` as well(note that it is not primitive type int, it is class Integer).

And be sure that the @Id comes from:

```
javax.persistence.Id
```